# Python Selenium GET with logged cookie or custom cookie

Tags: python, selenium

Is it possible for me to set a cookie with Selenium?

My cookie as I would like it is as follows:

`cookie=nsjsjshshs; cookie1=djdjjdjddh; ...`

How can I open an url (GET Method) with custom cookies?